# Sidekiq- will a worker's sidekiq_options override its superclass's options?

Tags: inheritance, configuration, sidekiq

Say I have a superclass worker like this:

```
class AppWorker
  sidekiq_options retry: false
  …
end
```

Now I want a specific worker class to retry

```
class StorageWorker < AppWorker
  sidekiq_options retry: true
  …
end
```

Will the subclass's options override be honored, ie will `retry` be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `sidekiq_options` does inherit as expected.

In the above example, `StorageWorker.sidekiq_options` will show `retry: true` and I've confirmed Sidekiq deals with it as such.